# JEST testing, getting error on import of configure from enzyme

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to run my tests in repo here: https://github.com/Futuratum/moon.holdings

But I'm getting the following error

> /Users/leongaban/projects/Futuratum/moon.holdings/jest.config.js:1
>   (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { configure } from 'enzyme'

My tests use to work and I haven't changed anything, so curious as to what could be causing this problem?

My **jest.config.js** file looks correct:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "moon.holdings",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Moon Holdings: track your cryptocurrency portfolio.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next -p 7777",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next -p 7777",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watch --no-cache",
    "test-win": "SET NODE_ENV=test&& jest --watch"
  },
  "author": "Futuratum",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "^1.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "decko": "^1.2.0",
    "next": "^8.0.4-canary.10",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "ramda-adjunct": "^2.17.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-adopt": "^0.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-ga": "^2.5.7",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "4.0.3",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4",
    "waait": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.15",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "@types/next": "^7.0.6",
    "@types/ramda": "^0.25.49",
    "@types/react": "^16.7.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/styled-components": "4.0.3",
    "@types/zeit__next-typescript": "^0.1.1",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-sass-vars": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "jest": "^24.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/.next/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "transform": {
      ".*": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.ts?$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/components/",
      "<rootDir>/pages/",
      "<rootDir>/shared/"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you accidentally renamed `jest.setup.js` to `jest.config.js` in [this commit](https://github.com/Futuratum/moon.holdings/commit/71b1b21150c4f2324048931d66fecb7d996bb51e#diff-2d0cd5d10b9604941c38c6aac608178a).

Change it back to `jest.setup.js` and it should work.

---

**Details**

`jest.config.js` is a special file that is used to set `Jest` [configuration options](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration).

`enzyme` configuration is typically done in a `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` file for older versions of `Jest` or [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) for newer versions of `Jest`.

Your `package.json` has `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` set to `jest.setup.js`.

Based on that info I suspected that maybe `jest.setup.js` got accidentally renamed, and was able to find the commit where it happened in the repo history.

Comment: Ah! That was it! Thanks :D